# Lazy registration with RESTful routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.1, registration, rails-routing

I'm stuck figuring out the best practice...

I want to create a "following" system in a way that a user can follow a car (getting email updates when car price changes, etc). The part of implementation that's giving me headaches is when I want to introduce lazy registration by only using email.

Everything **needs to work as AJAX** requests.

In the interface, there will be a button to trigger the follow action, which will check if the user is registered or not. If a user is logged in, create a new `CarSubscription` item, otherwise display a form where he could type his email address. Once submitted, the form should create a user with no password (if email exists, ask for the password and log in) and then it should create the relationship item.

The challenge here is to use redirection after submission of the form to the `CREATE` action of the `CarSubscriptionController`. Since I can't redirect using `POST` I can't simulate the `CREATE` or `DESTROY` action.

The non-RESTful solution would be to create 2 actions under `cars_controller`: follow and unfollow and let them do the logic of creating entries and deleting them. That would enable me to just store the request path and use it after the user enters their email and logs in.

**How can I achieve what I want using RESTful resources?**

After trying to describe my problem here, it seems it's way too complicated and I am indeed very stuck... There are 3 different controllers and possibly 4 requests in this scenario.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Please see my flow chart below:
[image: flow chart of follow action]

Comment: The description doesn't seem to be follow the diagram (or vice versa).  In the diagram, clicking the "Follow" button first creates a car subscription.  In the text you refer to it "[checking] if the user is registered or not".  It would help if you could either update the description or the diagram so they describe the same tentative behavior.

Comment: the square edge blocks in the diagram represent whenever an action of a controller is called. That doesn't mean that the actual entry is being created. What comes after the square is logic inside the controller until it enters another controller or action. I don't really know how to represent that in proper diagram language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert here, I don't know if it's the best solution, but what I have done in similar situation is :

1. In your controller, respond with javascript instead of redirecting the user
2. In your javascript file, use `$.post(...)` to issue a `POST` to your controller action
3. Et voilà!

You can also use ActiveResource to achieve this, but I actually never tried that solution : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#label-Custom+REST+methods

```
Person.new(:name => 'Ryan').post(:register)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think ActiveResource is more useful when having multiple applications instead of same application: [ActiveResource on RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics).

I already plan on responding with AJAX by having `link_to :remote => true`. But keeping it DRY means somehow accessing the methods in other controllers (users, sessions) to create users and logging in with password.

Comment: I definitely think you have a point with responding with a javascript file that sends post requests to the other controllers, which respond with json or smtg like that. So almost the whole logic is managed by the `#invitation_form` js view. This sound nice, I'll try to implement it!

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar need and had trouble pulling the various bits of info on how to do this with Devise and Rails together into a working example.  Here's a fully working example based on Rails 4, Ruby 2, and Devise 3.0:

https://github.com/mwlang/lazy_registration_demos